# Constructor interface: Class without matching constructor is still assignable

Tags: typescript

Imagine we have an interface which defines what arguments should constructor accept:

```
interface Ctr {
    new (num: number): any;
}
```

And then we have a class with default constructor:

```
class DefCtr {
}
```

Then, for some reason, I can assign `DefCtr` class to a variable of type `Ctr`:

```
const Instance: Ctr = DefCtr;

const i = new Instance(1);
console.log(i);

// The output is:
// DefCtr {}
```

So the `Instance` is a `DefCtr` class (which has no constructor accepting number). But interface is forcing me to pass a number (which will be ignored) when creating an instance of it.

What's interesting this works only when class has the default constructor. For example, this won't work:

```
interface Ctr {
    new (num: number): any;
}

class NotDefCtr {
    // Lets create a non-default constructor
    constructor(str: string) {
    }
}

const Instance: Ctr = NotDefCtr; // Error:

// Type 'typeof NotDefCtr' is not assignable to type 'Ctr'.
// Types of parameters 'str' and 'num' are incompatible.
// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Error makes sense. But from my point of view, it would also make sense to receive an error when trying to assign a class with default constructor (since it doesn't have any other constructor matching interface).

Comment: Read [the FAQ entry on functions of fewer parameters being assignable to functions of more parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters); this is the same issue except using a newable instead of a plain callable.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It makes sense... I think this could be the answer instead of comment. An accepted one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TypeScript FAQ has an entry: [Why are functions with fewer parameters assignable to functions that take more parameters?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters).  This is the same issue except with a newable instead of a callable.  I'll translate that entry to this case:

This is the expected and desired behavior. There is a [principle of substitutability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) that says that if an object `X` can be used in place of some object `Y`, then `X` is a *subtype* of or *assignable* to `Y`.

In this case, `DefCtr` is a subtype of `Ctr` because `DefCtr`'s constructor can safely ignore extra `number` parameter.  But `NotDefCtr` is *not* a subtype of `Ctr` because `NotDefCtr`'s type indicates that it expects an argument of type `string`; a `number` cannot safely be used as a `string`, so it's not compatible.

(Aside: it turns out that `NotDefCtr`'s constructor actually ignores its input, so at runtime no explosion would happen.  But the type system does not care about the particular implementation of the constructor; it sees the signature a contract saying that `NotDefCtr`'s constructor is within its rights to expect an argument of type `string`.  So it's still an error to substitute a `Ctr` with `NotDefCtr`.)

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!